# Make a TypeScript type which represents the first letter of a string type

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a function that outputs the first letter of the string passed into it. In my case I know what the possible values are, assume either hard-coded or through a generic, and want the function’s return type to be exactly what the letter being returned is, so I can pass this on to later functions.

I have actually found a rather inelegant way to do it, but I have a feeling that it’s not stable and may not work in future versions of TypeScript, as `${infer FirstLetter}` could technically represent any number of characters… it just so happens that TypeScript currently only finds the first one:

```ts
type Speed = 'fast' | 'slow' | 'medium';
type SpeedShort = Speed extends `${infer FirstLetter}${string}`
  ? FirstLetter
  : never;
```

As a function declaration this may look like:

```ts
declare function firstLetter<Letters extends string>(
  string: Letters,
): Letters extends `${infer FirstLetter}${string}`
  ? FirstLetter
  : never;
```

Comment: `could technically represent any number of characters…` Why would you think that?

Comment: @Brook Jordan. your function is ok. IT will work in future versions.

Comment: If you don't know the explicit value being passed into a function, you cannot assign an explicit type based on its return value. I believe this is a misplaced expectation between the purpose of types and values. A type should be viewed as a subset of values that can potentially exist in an object.

Comment: @Roberto Zvjerković because in the inference I see no reason why it couldn’t decide to pick 'fas' and leave string as 't' instead of picking only one letter.

Comment: @captain-yossarian how can you know?

Comment: @BrookJordan That would be kind of useless, since then it would just infer... Anything? String literal inference always infers the shortest possible character sequence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Frustratingly, the type `'test'[0]` isn’t `'t'`, it’s `string`. (Likewise, `'test'['length']` isn’t `4`, it’s `number`.) Clearly, string literal types are not as sophisticated in Typescript as tuple types are (both `[0]` and `['length']` would work as expected for `['t', 'e', 's', 't']`). There is [an open issue about this limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41037).

Like you, I viewed `` `${infer H}${infer T}` `` with some doubt. There’s nothing in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) that says it will always match exactly one character for the first `H` and the rest in `T`. There is, however, [a statement in the original pull request that describes exactly this behavior](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336#issue-689531932), saying:

> A placeholder immediately followed by another placeholder is matched by inferring a single character from the source.

Also, [in another comment, Anders says](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47048#issuecomment-1010327493):

> In general, immediately adjacent placeholders are really only useful for taking strings apart one character at a time.

suggesting that this is intended behavior that can be relied upon. I would like to find it in the docs, but given what we have, `` `${infer H}${string}` `` is probably safe, and certainly the best available situation so long as it is safe.

But if we *don’t* use that, there are still options. Not great ones, but they exist. For instance, an easy improvement on Oleksandr’s answer would be

```
function firstLetter<S extends Speed>(speed: S):
  S extends 'fast' ? 'f' :
  S extends 'medium' ? 'm' :
  S extends 'slow' ? 's' :
  never {
    // implementation
}
```

[See in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVKxgGcMAZEDDEGAHgGV4QAPK1YI+AckShM-gA+XALYhgWZMP5DORCDgDunAHwAKIgAcQYgFzw6ASh0AoePsYsQbDt14Z+Afi6J+Jsw2at2IsRKnwnTn83c08rb1l5JQCuIldTeFQQADdqAG5jY1V1LV1nO04jZ34AXmUCYjIKKhgc7WADAwzszXq9Wz5BWKjC9pcu2VLyxEISckpqOrFGtKA)

This will return precisely the first letter of whatever `Speed`(s) you give. So `firstLetter('fast')` won’t have a return type of `SpeedShort`, it’ll have a type of `f`. And `(speed: 'fast' | 'slow') => firstLetter(speed)` will have a return type of `'f' | 's'`.

More importantly, this perhaps suggests a more significant improvement:

```
type FirstLetterOf<S extends string> =
  string extends S ? string : // case where S is just string, not a literal type
  S extends `a${string}` ? 'a' :
  S extends `b${string}` ? 'b' :
  S extends `c${string}` ? 'c' :
  S extends `d${string}` ? 'd' :
  S extends `e${string}` ? 'e' :
  S extends `f${string}` ? 'f' :
  S extends `g${string}` ? 'g' :
  S extends `h${string}` ? 'h' :
  S extends `i${string}` ? 'i' :
  S extends `j${string}` ? 'j' :
  S extends `l${string}` ? 'l' :
  S extends `m${string}` ? 'm' :
  S extends `n${string}` ? 'n' :
  S extends `o${string}` ? 'o' :
  S extends `p${string}` ? 'p' :
  S extends `q${string}` ? 'q' :
  S extends `r${string}` ? 'r' :
  S extends `s${string}` ? 's' :
  S extends `t${string}` ? 't' :
  S extends `u${string}` ? 'u' :
  S extends `v${string}` ? 'v' :
  S extends `w${string}` ? 'w' :
  S extends `x${string}` ? 'x' :
  S extends `y${string}` ? 'y' :
  S extends `z${string}` ? 'z' :
  string;

function firstLetter<S extends string>(s: S): FirstLetterOf<S> { /*…*/ }
```

[See in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgJwM7ADIWMCCDyAzAHgGUoIAPLAOwBMkoUE5KBzAPigF4AoKe4RlqQoQadEgH4+A5lABcUAPQKoAYwCGSaAHcAFtmgk4dAFYBXFFKbMANFEoB7YFDVQANnCwI1rqKEg8oEnIqWigAAzUAEgBvBisAXzCoSQByNRS5AKDhUXCAIxi4lkTkqBS8jNksoRC6MJVC-gSk1JVK6uCRULDqRukS1Op23mza8Ig+5tKUiGHAmq66vEnilrK8OdHF8OYV5gGy5k2F3LCdPYOUnWPO07gLtZS4G5zu4wfp4xexsNcP1Nc322YQAtv8yiCgadKOCUpQod17LD7Ai6mBYWBUeEAI6w7FYsIIWEIAlIWFIAnAWHAAmmWGmAkAN1hjIJWlhWgJZFhZAJIFhIAJAC9YUK5kVmABuLhcagQFSuNQIaB4UyUFTAOD2ShQPCIFDoTDYfDEE6hCWsAAUSHkRAAlPJ4Mg0BhPCaiKxpVwVNqLFgLBxdfqXUbcHhLSl-TS7ZKgA)

This will extract the first letter... as long as we define “letter” as `a-z`. You can, of course, extend it... but only up to a point. Typescript has a rather low nested condition limit, and that’s already 27 layers deep. Add uppercase letters and you’re up to 53.

A common solution to nested condition issues in situations like these is to use a mapping type, and walk through that rather than nesting all the possibilities. That is, this:

```
type Letter =
  | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i' | 'j' | 'k' | 'l' | 'm'
  | 'n' | 'o' | 'p' | 'q' | 'r' | 's' | 't' | 'u' | 'v' | 'w' | 'x' | 'y' | 'z'
  ;

type FirstLetterOf<S extends string> =
  string extends S ? string : // case where S is just string, not a literal type
  {
    [L in Letter]: S extends `${L}${string}` ? L : never;
  }[Letter];

function firstLetter<S extends string>(s: S): FirstLetterOf<S> { /*…*/ }
```

[See in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhzAgJygXgFBSgHygcgEM8d8AjY3PAYwvwBNa8JGAzRgc0YAtGBLRgFaMA1owA2jALZ5MJPADtGAe0ZhGAR0ZJGAZ0bBGAV0YA3RgHdGAD0YhGALxlYA3OnShIUAGK8kO4HAIyADyLAA8AMpQEFaI8nQ6UP5IvPLsAHxossmp7NGxEPGJUQD8ScApaVAAXLIA3rJYANowUKmw8IhIALrVUFExcQlQAAYAJHUwAL4TOWlTI1BlrX3yECbIrlhTLZ3I3a7odBBUYgRI0CyG8lTAvEryUCy+-oFdkflDiXMZABQ6fQiAEo+j4-AE9khQpF0odfv9IBA6H08CwCP5dGIlJYQfg2HI9GhMs9wW9kAiIEigUDXPCdIjkfhrrwqEokIpcXhjESni8IUEkBSqTT0HSGX0frifjySa9IUK6NTnEA)

Now, we no longer have nested conditions, we just have one condition that we run for each `Letter`. Now it’s relatively easy to add letters, and while there’s still a limit on how many we can add, it’s now *very* large.

This still has a problem: if you put in a string literal that doesn’t start with a `Letter`, the turn type is `never`. That’s not right; it should probably be `string` (as in, our type isn’t smart enough to narrow down *which* string we’ll end up with but we’re going to end up with one). Fixing that... looks nasty, but it remains performant and safe from nesting limits:

```
type Letter =
  | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f' | 'g' | 'h' | 'i' | 'j' | 'k' | 'l' | 'm'
  | 'n' | 'o' | 'p' | 'q' | 'r' | 's' | 't' | 'u' | 'v' | 'w' | 'x' | 'y' | 'z'
  ;

type FirstLetterOf<S extends string> =
  string extends S ? string : // case where S is just string, not a literal type
  {
    [L in Letter]: S extends `${L}${string}` ? L : never;
  }[Letter] extends infer L
    ? [L, never] extends [never, L]
      ? string
      : L
    : never;

function firstLetter<S extends string>(s: S): FirstLetterOf<S> { /*…*/ }
```

[See in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMhzAgJygXgFBSgHygcgEM8d8AjY3PAYwvwBNa8JGAzRgc0YAtGBLRgFaMA1owA2jALZ5MJPADtGAe0ZhGAR0ZJGAZ0bBGAV0YA3RgHdGAD0YhGALxlYA3OnShIUAGK8kO4HAIyADyLAA8AMpQEFaI8nQ6UP5IvPLsAHxossmp7NGxEPGJUQD8ScApaVAAXLIA3rJYANowUKmw8IhIALrVUFExcQlQAAYAJHUwAL4TOWlTI1BlrX3yECbIrlhTLZ3I3flDiaksyLCNS1AtADRQaxs9h4XDTffItzDdF1hlc+zfNXOWCwq3WmzcdAgVDEBCQ0BYhnkVGAvCU8igLF8-kCXUiTyK5UqGQAFDo+hEAJR9Hx+AJ7JChSLpVzoYmkyAQOh9PAsAj+XRiJSWKn4NhyPRoTKY2k45DsiCcikU1xsnQcrn4RG8KhKJCKEV4YySjFYulBJDyxXK1mWjV-EV-Y3S7H021KlW27kAQQAQgAlL0AYS9ABFfQG8A6KrknabZRa1Qq6O6gA)

The `extends infer L` business effectively saves the result of the type in type `L`, and then `[L, never] extends [never, L]` is a way to check if `L` is `never`—that is, none of our `Letter`s matched. If so, our type is `string` instead. If not, we just go with `L`, since that means a `Letter` matched and that’s what we want to use. The last `: never` is there as the “false case” for the condition `blah blah extends infer L`, which can’t ever be false since we `infer L` to be whatever `blah blah` actually is, so of course `blah blah` extends it. The syntax here is... weird, but it works. We do have a few layers of nested conditions here, but it’s a fixed number that doesn’t change no matter how many `Letter`s we add, so that’s fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, the result fails to extend `string` for further transformation. Example [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wy6KZw): adding one line `type UppercaseFirstLetterOf<S extends string> = Uppercase<FirstLetterOf<S>>;` produces an error on the type parameter to Uppercase that "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'." I'm also not finding a cast strategy that works - any ideas?

Comment: For those coming after, skipping the last step in this answer derivation seems to solve that particular issue and might be OK depending on your application setting's risk for the last step's motivation.

Comment: @WBT The solution, if you want both, is to just through a few more hoops and use `Uppercase<FirstLetterOf<S> extends infer F extends string ? F : never>`; see [here](https://tsplay.dev/m0nrGw). Stupid jumping through hoops to get TS to understand that it’s always gonna be a string, but you do it once, slap a comment on it if you need to, and then you can use the type from then on without problems.

Answer (score -2):

Here's how you declare such type:

```js
type Speed = 'fast' | 'slow' | 'medium'
type SpeedShort = 'f' | 's' | 'm'
```

And here's how you implement conversion function:

```js
function firstLetter(speed: Speed): SpeedShort {
    switch (speed) {
        case 'fast': return 'f'
        case 'slow': return 's'
        case 'medium': return 'm'
    }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAypEBMoF4oHIBmBDAzsNUAPujgDYD2A7gcWgLaICWArnWgFCiSzwIwAW5AE7AU6DDRKT6HdhmYA7AMbBG5BVAyMheADIRgwCEIAUOXgC4eERAEorcG30EioAb3ZQvUHJUbAlfigzXlt3T29IpVxoTFx8KyEDZiENTA5IqJiSCmpE5NSpCMyoaJxYhgQWNnzgFLS2YqgAX3ZmoA)

I know that it is more code to write.
However, this code still expresses the intent and is validated by a compiler correctly leaving no place for human error (i.e. changing one type without changing the mapping function will result in compile-time error).

Comment: I have a function that works great, this isn’t the issue. There are many different ways to get the first character of a string in JavaScript while checking for errors such as having a zero-length string. I just want to make sure that the types are, and will always be, working well. So I do agree that this way would work well, but as I already have one way that works in the current system of Typescript I was wondering if someone could come up with a more solid typing implementation.

Comment: @BrookJordan what is not solid enough in this approach?

Comment: Apologies, I was referring to my solution as not being solid enough, but having read the comments of others it looks like it may be more solid than I had expected. As for your answer, it is solid. The issue is that I was looking for a way to infer in a more generic way which would work on any given type so I don't have to create a new first-letter function for each use-case.